# VirtualService hosts and minikube

Tags: kubernetes, istio, minikube

In [this](https://github.com/behrangsa/hello-k8s/tree/stackoverflow) project, let's say I set the value of [hosts](https://github.com/behrangsa/hello-k8s/blob/stackoverflow/deployment/kustomize/base/virtualservice.yaml#L7) to `hello`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s
spec:
  hosts:
    - ???
  http:
    - name: hello-k8s
      match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: hello               # <--------------
            port:
              number: 8080
```

After deploying the project to my local minikube:

- What domain name should I send my requests to? `hello.local`?

```sh
$ curl what.should.be.here:8080
```

- Is there a way to find it out using `kubectl` and introspection?

---

*Update 1:*

I changed the host to `hello.local`.

Then I verified that `istio` is enabled in `minikube`:

```
➜ minikube addons list
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
|         ADDON NAME          | PROFILE  |    STATUS    |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
| ambassador                  | minikube | disabled     |
| csi-hostpath-driver         | minikube | disabled     |
| dashboard                   | minikube | disabled     |
| default-storageclass        | minikube | enabled ✓    |
| efk                         | minikube | disabled     |
| freshpod                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gcp-auth                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gvisor                      | minikube | disabled     |
| helm-tiller                 | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress                     | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | disabled     |
| istio                       | minikube | enabled ✓    |
| istio-provisioner           | minikube | enabled ✓    |
| kubevirt                    | minikube | disabled     |
| logviewer                   | minikube | disabled     |
| metallb                     | minikube | disabled     |
| metrics-server              | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-driver-installer     | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin    | minikube | disabled     |
| olm                         | minikube | disabled     |
| pod-security-policy         | minikube | disabled     |
| registry                    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-aliases            | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-creds              | minikube | disabled     |
| storage-provisioner         | minikube | enabled ✓    |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | minikube | disabled     |
| volumesnapshots             | minikube | disabled     |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
```

I deployed the app and verified everything is working:

```
➜ kubectl apply -k base/
service/hello-k8s unchanged
deployment.apps/hello-k8s unchanged
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/hello-k8s configured

➜ kubectl get deployments/hello-k8s
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-k8s   1/1     1            1           20h

➜ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-k8s-6d9cc7d655-plzs8   1/1     Running   0          20h

➜ kubectl get service/hello-k8s
NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
hello-k8s   ClusterIP   10.98.144.226   <none>        8080/TCP   21h

➜ kubectl get virtualservice/hello-k8s
NAME        GATEWAYS   HOSTS             AGE
hello-k8s              ["hello.local"]   20h

➜ kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-ingressgateway-8577c95547-6c9sk   1/1     Running   0          21h
istiod-6ccd677dc7-7cvr2                 1/1     Running   0          21h
prometheus-7767dfd55-x2pv6              2/2     Running   0          21h
```

Not sure why I have to do this, but apparently it should be done:

```
➜ kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled --overwrite
namespace/default labeled

➜ kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection
NAME              STATUS   AGE   ISTIO-INJECTION
default           Active   21h   enabled
istio-operator    Active   21h
istio-system      Active   21h   disabled
kube-node-lease   Active   21h
kube-public       Active   21h
kube-system       Active   21h
playground        Active   21h
```

I inspected the ip of `minikube` and added an entry to /etc/hosts for `hello.local`:

```
➜  minikube ip
192.168.49.2

➜ tail -n 3  /etc/hosts

# Minikube
192.168.49.2    hello.local
```

Then I queried the port of `istio-ingressgateway` according to [this blog post](https://shekhargulati.com/2019/03/05/istio-minikube-tutorial-deploying-a-hello-world-example-application-with-istio-in-kubernetes/):

```
➜ kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}'
30616
```

Finally I sent a request to `hello.local:30616`, but the requests are not arriving at my app:

```
➜ curl -iv hello.local:30616/hello
*   Trying 192.168.49.2:30616...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hello.local (192.168.49.2) port 30616 (#0)
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: hello.local:30616
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 14:51:18 GMT
date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 14:51:18 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
server: istio-envoy
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0

<
* Connection #0 to host hello.local left intact
```

Comment: Hello @Behrang, is your problem still unresolved?

Answer (score 1):

**What domain name should I send my requests to?  `hello.local`?**

The answer would be that you can use whatever the domain you want but you will be required to add this domain in `/etc/hosts`. Then `/etc/hosts` domain will be the ip address of the [istio gateway loadbalancer](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports).
Thanks to it you will be able to use that domain instead of the ingress gateway ip

**Moving on there are couple of things about hosts/host in Virtual Service to consider:**

If you set virtual service `hosts` value to just `hello` then as per documentation Istio will interpret the short name based on the namespace of the rule, not the service. A rule in the `default` namespace with host `hello` will be interpreted as `hello.default.svc.cluster.local`.

You can also reference services along domains in hosts.

**So to avoid potential misconfigurations, it is recommended to always use fully qualified domain names over short names.**

Now coming next to `destination.host`:

> The name of a service from the service registry. Service names are
> looked up from the platform’s service registry (e.g., Kubernetes
> services, Consul services, etc.) and from the hosts declared by
> [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/#ServiceEntry).
> Traffic forwarded to destinations that are not found in either of the
> two, will be dropped.

Here's also a [good exmpale](https://medium.com/@emirmujic/istio-and-metallb-on-minikube-242281b1134b) how to configure metallb as loadbalancer and istio in minikube. Having metallb will give your service automatically configure as loadbalancer.

---

After further checking into your case I figure that problem might be related to your [gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/.) not being used at all:

```sh
➜ kubectl get virtualservice/hello-k8s
NAME        GATEWAYS   HOSTS             AGE
hello-k8s              ["hello.local"]   20h ## Gateway describes a load balancer operating at the edge of the mesh receiving incoming or outgoing HTTP/TCP connections.
```

> "Gateway describes a load balancer operating at the edge of the mesh
> receiving incoming or outgoing HTTP/TCP connections. Using Istio
> Gateway configuration you can bind VirtualService via
> virtualservice.spec.gateways with specific gateways (allowing external
> traffic or internal traffic inside istio service mesh) "The reserved
> word mesh is used to imply all the sidecars in the mesh. When this
> field is omitted, the default gateway (mesh) will be used"
> https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService

Make sure you configure `Gateway` and `VirtualService`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway  ### this should be verified with istio ingress gateway pod labels
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"   ### for specific hosts it can be f.e. hello.local
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s
spec:
  hosts:
    - hello.local
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: hello-k8s.default.svc.cluster.local 
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: I still have trouble making this work. I will post an update in a second.

Comment: Your `route.destination` is incorrect. Your k8s service name is `hello-k8s` while you are referencing `hello`. Also it seems that in example that you provided the app is listening on `/hello`. This would require you to change `uri.prefix` to `/hello`.

Comment: The app respons to both `/` and `/hello`: https://github.com/behrangsa/hello-k8s/blob/master/cmd/api/main.go#L12-L13.

Comment: @βξhrαng I have edited my answer. Can you have a look please?